# If USB is backwards-compatible, why does my PC have both USB 2 and USB 3 female connectors?

Tags: usb

My HP tower, bought three years ago, has on the front:

- USB 2 with charging ability
- USB 2 without charging ability
- USB 3
- USB 3

Why would they make any connector USB 2 when USB 3 was already a thing when the computer was made and it's backwards-compatible?

And why don't all connectors have "charging ability"? What is the point of dividing them up like this?

Comment: Consider the possibility that having charging ability might entail additional hardware internally, and thus omitting it may reduce cost; similarly, the USB2 support might be less expensive to build into the box than USB3 support.

Answer (score 4):

There are many potential reasons.

- cost: a USB 2 controller is less expensive and is more than enough for many devices
- bandwidth: CPUs have a limited total bandwidth for the communications with the peripherals (including drives, graphic card, etc...), and 4 USB 3 ports working at their full speed would be too much for many CPUs. Sure, they could share the bandwidth through an internal hub, but these would not be independent ports, then.
- power: a USB 3 port is required to deliver 0.9A, compared to 0.5A for a USB 2 port. On a desktop it's not a big deal but on some laptops it can be.

Answer (score 1):

Newer USB versions are always backwards compatible with older versions.

That being said, USB hardware, especially versions 3 and newer are very different than older versions.  USB 3 has more pins and support for higher power delivery.

Making USB connectors and supporting higher power delivery costs more money to manufacture.  Therefore it costs more to be put into a computer.  Since many USB devices, like keyboards, mice, printers, etc do not require high speed or power there is no need to plug them into USB3+ connections.  Heck, you can use them perfectly on USB 1.0.  The computer manufacturer provides cheaper USB2 connections for these.

Also, some USB2 connections allow for power, even when the device is off.  This is for charging devices, without turning the computer on.